# css. rotate3d. вращение элемента

Tags: css, css3, геометрия, transform

В 3D редакторах используют систему координат:
[image: xyz]

В Web используют такую систему:
[image: zxy]

В первом случаи *ось y* идет вверх в плюсовом значении, а в низ следственно в минусовую. Система координат в браузере отличается разным наименование осей, а так же *ось y* противоположно производит вычисления относительно первого примера. Можете разъяснить разницу между этими системами координат, и как определить в какую сторону будет производиться поворот с помощью `css` свойства `rotate()`? На второй картинке указано куда будет производится поворот, но я не пойму по какой закономерности. Я пытался читать, но не особо нашел по этому поводу информацию, которую будет легко воспринять.

**P.S:** Нашел инфу по поводу поворотов. Читаю про **Кватернион**, **Углы Эйлера** и **Матрица поворота**, но вопрос еще актуален.